# How to create real-world map with Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, mapbox

I need to work on Unity in order to create an Android Application with a map like in the game Pokemon Go. The player will be geolocated and will have some geolocated challenge to succeed. Except that I'm a beginner with Unity and I wondered which asset should I use to build this app.

I took a look at **Go Map** : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/68889, which seems to be very great for what I want to do (I don't mind the price).

There is also **WRLD Unity SDK** : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/86284, that came out on July 5th. It is free but all areas are not implemented yet, like the one where I live. On their website, they inform their users that it will be implemented within a month. Should I wait?

I tried to use the **mapbox SDK** : https://www.mapbox.com/unity-sdk/, but I can't find the information I want in their documentation, and there are not a lot of tutorials on their website (some of them are incomplete, like this one that would have been really helpful for me : https://www.mapbox.com/help/unity-mesh-pt-1/).

In the end, I'm kind of lost and I don't know where to start and how to start. Could someone give me some advices about which asset to use?

Comment: We've posted some updates to our tutorial page. Below are some links to more on the mesh generation set. https://www.mapbox.com/help/unity-mesh-pt-2/ https://www.mapbox.com/help/unity-mesh-pt-3/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend google maps API if you want something very professional. You'll have to code for it outside of unity's ecosystem, but you'll get a very refined product. It has built in android and IOS support too.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#whatis